# pH of dilute acids in hexane

Tags: acid-base, ph

Consider a strong acid $\ce{HA}$. In a $\pu{1000 mL}$ of hexane (assume it is unable to accept a proton) we "dissolve" (this can mean forming a suspension with vigorous stirring - otherwise we can use a polar solvent which cannot accept a proton) $\pu{1e-30 mol}$ of the acid along with enough water to remove all the protons.

Now we have extremely dilute solution of $\ce{H+}$ where autoprotolysis is insignificant compared to the volume of solvent, so according to $\mathrm{pH} = -\log[\ce{H+}]$, pH should be extremely high. However, we are still using an acid, so pH should not be too high. What accounts for the difference?

Comment: Interesting. pKa values are given for alkanes (generally pKa >60) and other non-water compounds. pKa is the pH where half of it exists protonated/unprotonated /deprotonated, so this would suggest pH can be measured in non-aqueous solutions.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/72/determining-the-ph-of-an-organic-solvent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pH is ***defined*** for water solutions; using it elsewhere is either impossible or leads to contradictory results like yours. Who said pH should not be too high? Well, you might argue that high pH implies *alkaline* solution, does it not? No, it doesn't. Alkaline solutions are (roughly speaking) those with high concentration of $\ce{OH-}$. In water this means the same thing, because $\ce{[H+]\cdot[OH-]=10^{-14}}$, so low $\ce{[H+]}$ means high $\ce{[OH-]}$ and vice versa. In hexane, not really.

To determine pKa values which are way beyond the physically possible range of pH, we extend it with things like [Hammet's $H_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammett_acidity_function), and thus build a [ladder](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28022/how-is-the-pka-of-extremely-weak-acids-determined/42574#42574) of measures suitable for a much wider range. You may call it "*effective pH*" or like that, but remember: it has little to do with literal concentration of $\ce{H+}$, and your hypothetical solution of $\ce{10^{-30}M\; HCl}$ in hexane is in fact neither acidic nor basic.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think the pH (activity) can be theoretically applied to non-aqueous solutions (http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/chem.201003164/abstract;jsessionid=6237E1A09F29EE5D07AA17B2658C677B.f03t03), but it isn't very convenient.